# How does bit-wise operation work for encrypting grayscale images?

Tags: encryption, keys, randomness, one-time-pad, steganography

How does bit-wise operation work for encrypting grayscale images?

In my Khan Academy course they encrypt an image with `bitwise_and`, `bitwise_or` and `bitwise_xor`. I have tried, without success, to replicate their results.

The Khan Academy write-up: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/ciphers/a/xor-and-the-one-time-pad

My results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD6jJ.jpg

The way I did the operation is this (Python code):

```
def get_bitwise_image(image, key, op):

    and_image = []
    row=0
    col=0
    while row < len(image):
        new_row = []
        col = 0
        while col < len(image[row]):
            # a bitwise and between say 243 and 1 is bitwise and between 2 intergers and not binaries. So, their constituent bits and and-ed together
            # ex: 1 => 00000001 and 243 => 11110011
            # 00000001
            # 11110011
            # --------
            # 00000001 => 1
            if op == 'and':
                new_row.append(image[row, col] & key[row, col])
            elif op == 'or':
                new_row.append(image[row, col] | key[row, col])
            else:
                new_row.append(image[row, col] ^ key[row, col])
            col += 1
        and_image.append(new_row)
        row+=1
    return and_image
```

My second image is grayscale with values `0-255`, and my key is a matrix of the same dimensions as an image with random 1s and 0s.

Key is defined as: `key = numpy.random.randint(0, 2, image.shape)`

Why is the Khan Academy's result completely different from mine? How are grayscale images encrypted with bit-wise operations?

Comment: Well, your original images are different, and so the scan rasters might be different in the low bits.  Please repeat with Abe...

Comment: There is no standardized way of doing this. So if you want identical results you need to replicate what has been done before. Closing this question as it cannot be answered and will mainly involve coding theory rather than cryptography.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I believe the problem is with the key selection which only randomizes the least significant bit, so I'm not quite sure why you say it cannot be answered (I believe the OP asking why his result is different is an euphemism for asking what's wrong with his implementation), and unless I'm mistaken the key selection is a cryptography concern.

Comment: i have solved the problem. The problem was that I'm supposed to use logical AND instead of bitwise AND. I re-tried my test and results match. Unfortunately this question has been put on hold so I cannot post answer with code until its open again. these are the new results: https://imgur.com/a/NLa5Q8J

Comment: I'm glad you've solved this Paramdeep (Is that really your name or a nick? Sounds very hacky :) ). However, I think that solution is very specific to the assignment rather than cryptography in general.

Comment: @SleuthEye Sure, but implementation related issues are not on topic, I don't see how this question can be beneficial to anybody studying crypto in general. If you disagree with that, I'm fine with reopening the question on any good argument for it.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes posting the answer would only do good. Though the solution is implementation specific. It's good to know difference between bitwise and logical. My name is indian, thanks.

Comment: Oh, heck, I don't see it as doing any harm, so I'll reopen it. Anybody who sees this as an argument to post implementation specific questions: no, they are still off topic. I may migrate this to StackOverflow if there are objections.

Comment: That's a seriously good name for a programmer, you can thank your parents for that one :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.

The main reason was that I'm supposed to use LOGICAL operations instead of BITWISE operations.

The new results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zQNv.jpg

my function:

```
def logical_xor(message, key, op):
    message = np.asarray(message)
    key = np.asarray(key)
    new_image = []
    row=0
    col=0
    while row < len(message):
        new_row = []
        col = 0
        while col < len(message[row]):
            if op == 'and':
                new_row.append(message[row, col] and key[row, col]) # and instead of &
            elif op == 'or':
                new_row.append(message[row, col] or key[row, col])
            else:
                new_row.append(message[row, col] !=  key[row, col]) # xor
            col += 1
        new_image.append(new_row)
        row+=1
    return new_image
```

but before using this function, I had to do this:

```
from PIL import Image
m = Image.open("test_image.jpg") # message
m = m.convert("1") # converts to boolean?
```